# How does a non-root user use the Nagios mongodb plugin?

Tags: linux, mongodb, pymongo, nagios

I have not been able to use a non-root user with nagios mongodb plugin from this github repo :https://github.com/mzupan/nagios-plugin-mongodb.

For example: I can run this:

```
./check_mongodb.py -H 'ip address'-P 27017 -u 'root admin user' -p 'password for admin' -A database_size -d 'database_name' -W 100 -C 1000 and
```

get a response as follows: OK - Database size: 0 MB Database: database_name

but if i run it as a non-root user of my mongodb installation, it would happen as follows:

```
/check_mongodb.py -H 'ip-address'  -P 27017 -u 'non-root user'  -p 'password'  -A database_size -d 'database_name' -W 100 -C 1000
```

Result:

> CRITICAL - General MongoDB Error: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'non-root user'), ('nonce', u'565kp3321886122'), ('key', u'92309330endweqjwje')]) on namespace admin.$cmd failed: auth failed

I can tell the authentication failed, but im not sure where it is failing in check_mongodb.py. So can the plugin only be run as the root user or is there a way to run it as other mongodb users?